# How to use google map in fragment in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am trying to use google map api in a fragment but it always return null. I cant handle it any help will be appriciated. There is code;

```
public class Map extends android.app.Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    String response_vehicles;
    Location location;
    float map_zoom=14;
    public Map() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mapView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, null, false);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return mapView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Sydney")
                .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
                .position(sydney));
    }
}
```

And there is xml file;

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".Fragments.Map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

I gives error at mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); NullPointerException how can I solve this problem ? Manifest file and permissions are totaly true I think.

Comment: Extend the class with FragmentActivity and you should use supportMapFragment

Comment: Check this tutorial - http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/  Hope it will help

Comment: use `getChilFragmentManager()`

Comment: But I must use fragment because I am using floating action menu to pass between fragments.

Comment: Raghunandan I change it as getChildFragmentManager() but it still gives null.

Comment: make sure your map key is same as you create and its you define inside manifest

Comment: @Vishal Halani they are same there is no problem in manifest.

Comment: you get blank?? map right?

Comment: Extend AppCompactActivity then getsupportFragmentmanager();

Comment: I cant extend it to appcompatactivity it is a fragment I must use it as a fragment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116981/discussion-between-vishal-halani-and-mesopotamia).

Answer (score 3):

Here is Solution to use map in fragment class

Fragment Class

```
public class DemoMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private View rootView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_demo, container, false);
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mapFragment).commit();
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;

    }

}
```

And your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_demo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it requires a supportMapFragment but I use android.app.Fragment how can I solve this?

Comment: Fragment fragment = null;
                fragment = new Map();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit(); 
I am doing fragment transaction on that way now it gives error

Comment: change it to v4 support

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Android Latest version.

Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1

Gradle version: 7.0.3

Here is the map solution in fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = FragmentMapBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();

    mMapView = binding.mapView;
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.onResume();


    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(requireActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
            googleMap = mMap;


            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                requestPermissions(new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                }, 0);
            } else {
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }


            // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description"));

            // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(15).build();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
    });

    return root;
}
```

XML file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.map.MapFragment">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The result is same like this image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHV4z.png)

Comment: In android latest version, it is used the View Binding.